# is it possible to have mean(x) work and summary(x) at the same time

Tags: r

New to R, a professor gave us a trick? question if the following is possible:

Have a random .csv file that includes 6 variables of weather measurement and the following code working:

```
>x=read.table("x.csv",header=T,sep=",")
>attach(x)
>names(x)
>summary(x)
>mean(x)
```

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to have mean(x) work or am I wrong? All the previous code should work perfectly but the mean(x) should have an error of:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Is it possible? I'm genuinely new to R and wondering if there's some smart work around

Comment: If the variables are all numeric, you can do `mean(as.matrix(x))`. This will give you the mean of all the numeric variables in the data frame (which probably doesn't make any sense). If you have some characters or factors, the operation certainly doesn't make any sense. The other option is to try `colMeans(x)` which gives the mean for each variable in x.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(379)`